# Google Sheets: Making an Arrrayformula for Filter Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently upgrading my sheets for an MTB program.
I'm changing all my formulas to arrayformula so as to avoid anyone being left out when I forgot to drag the formula.

All that's left is the formula in cell P3. The formula is to sum the best 3 times for both categories of M and E.

Here's the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cRINly3eiB5DXvug4AxyqmZtp7nU8rVo2lR58WC1trQ/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet.

Any help is highly appreciated.

I want to sum the best 3 times for both categories of M and E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en), like this:

`={"BEST";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:INDEX(E:E,MAX(ROW(E:E)*(E:E<>"")))=E2:INDEX(E:E,MAX(ROW(E:E)*(E:E<>""))-1),,MAP(E3:E,LAMBDA(team,IF(COUNT(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team,D:D="M"))<3,"DNQ",IF(COUNT(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team,D:D="E"))<3,"DNQ",IF(COUNT(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team))<6,"DNQ",SMALL(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team,D:D="M"),3)+SMALL(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team,D:D="M"),2)+MIN(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team,D:D="M"))+SMALL(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team,D:D="E"),3)+SMALL(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team,D:D="E"),2)+MIN(FILTER(K:K,E:E=team,D:D="E")))))))))}`

I entered this formula in cell Q2.

Comment: Hi there! Could u help me a little bit more? I'm trying to arrayformula the formula in cell J3. The one I've made before (with query) has error when there are nothing to lookup, and there's an error in range.